# Trying Uniswap V3 Swap Example - Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract address

Tags: solidity, testing, hardhat-deploy, uniswapv3, alchemy

Have been getting bellow error message:

1. SwapExamples
   swapExactInputSingle:
   Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
   at SwapExamples.swapExactInputSingle (contracts/SwapExamples.sol:48)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
   at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
   at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
   at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
   at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
   at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)

My codes below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity >=0.7.6 < 0.9.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

contract SwapExamples {
    // NOTE: Does not work with SwapRouter02
    ISwapRouter public constant swapRouter =
        ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
   
    address public constant WETH9 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    
    address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;
    

    /// @notice Swaps a fixed amount of WETH for a maximum possible amount of DAI
    function swapExactInputSingle(uint amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint amountOut)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            WETH9,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
        .ExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: WETH9,
            tokenOut: DAI,
            // pool fee 0.3%
            fee: 3000,
            recipient: msg.sender,
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum: 0,
            // NOTE: In production, this value can be used to set the limit
            // for the price the swap will push the pool to,
            // which can help protect against price impact
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
        });
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }

    /// @notice swaps a minimum possible amount of WETH for a fixed amount of DAI.
    function swapExactOutputSingle(uint amountOut, uint amountInMaximum)
        external
        returns (uint amountIn)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            WETH9,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountInMaximum
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), amountInMaximum);

        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactOutputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: WETH9,
                tokenOut: DAI,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutputSingle(params);

        if (amountIn < amountInMaximum) {
            // Reset approval on router
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), 0);
            // Refund WETH to user
            TransferHelper.safeTransfer(
                WETH9,
                msg.sender,
                amountInMaximum - amountIn
            );
        }
    }

    /// @notice swapInputMultiplePools swaps a fixed amount of WETH for a maximum possible amount of DAI
    /// swap WETH --> USDC --> DAI
    function swapExactInputMultihop(uint amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint amountOut)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            WETH9,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(
                    WETH9,
                    uint24(3000),
                    USDC,
                    uint24(100),
                    DAI
                ),
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            });
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);
    }

    /// @notice swapExactOutputMultihop swaps a minimum possible amount of WETH for a fixed amount of USDC
    /// swap WETH --> USDC --> DAI
    function swapExactOutputMultihop(uint amountOut, uint amountInMaximum)
        external
        returns (uint amountIn)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            WETH9,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountInMaximum
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), amountInMaximum);

        // The parameter path is encoded as (tokenOut, fee, tokenIn/tokenOut, fee, tokenIn)
        ISwapRouter.ExactOutputParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactOutputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(
                    DAI,
                    uint24(100),
                    USDC,
                    uint24(3000),
                    WETH9
                ),
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountOut: amountOut,
                amountInMaximum: amountInMaximum
            });

        amountIn = swapRouter.exactOutput(params);
        if (amountIn < amountInMaximum) {
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), 0);
            TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
                WETH9,
                address(this),
                msg.sender,
                amountInMaximum - amountIn
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```
const {expect} = require('chai')
const {ethers} = require('hardhat')


const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
const WETH9 = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
const USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"

describe("SwapExamples" , function(){

    it("swapExactInputSingle" , async function(){

        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

        const dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI)
        const weth = await ethers.getContractAt("IWETH", WETH9)
        const usdc = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", USDC)

        const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapExamples")

        const swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy();
        await swapExamples.deployed()

        const amountIn = 10n ** 18n

        // deposit eth
        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).deposit({value : amountIn})
        await weth.connect(accounts[0]).approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn)

        await swapExamples.swapExactInputSingle(amountIn)

        console.log("DAI Balance" , await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address))


    })
})
```

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  netwroks:{
    hardhat:{
      forking:{
        url:'https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/OspEaXXiwDtQLFSg-_3JKNw0o9myCmik'
      }
    }
  }
};
```